# See You Again with a one-line wonder

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I have three faces, two sides and one rear end.

What am I?

---

I haven't been on Puzzling in a while. After my 100th post, I took a break. But I thought now I'd come around again. The riddle might be easy, but I'll find out soon enough. Enjoy :P

> Two very subtle hints are in the title. (The spoiler below identifies them.)

> ***Cu Ag**ain with a one-line wonder*

Comment: Well now, a new puzzle from Mr. Pie?  Hope all has been well!

Comment: *rear end* has a clear meaning: butt. What you have in mind has no butt. So it's misleading unless someone forgets their idiomatic English. Or unless you have a one with a literal butt on it. Who knows, perhaps there's one with a hippo on it or something, with butt in plain sight? :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I suppose you are right. I originally phrased the riddle as "... and one end" but I feared that in this phrasing, the word "end" would be realised temporally (e.g. one's end of their lifetime) as opposed to spatially (e.g. the ends of a string), the latter of which is the intended meaning. I thought *that* would have been misleading haha, ironically. But I think you are right. I'll select my words a bit more carefully next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Coin

> A coin has two sides, tails (rear end) and someone's face (so three "faces"?)

> Hint is metals: copper (Cu) and silver (Ag)

Comment: This is the intended answer. Well done! +1

Comment: Maybe the added hint gave too much away :P

Comment: Haha, I'll make my hints in future questions a bit less disclosing. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 6):

Is it a

> CUBE?

> A cube has 6 faces, but you could call the 2 on it's right and left its "sides" and it is sitting on its rear end. The subtle hints are C U again.

> A Cerberus also works with the same logic but that seems more like a dictionary definition.

Comment: That is not the intended answer, but damn that is a convincing attempt, so +1 from me. (I knew that a one-line riddle would run the risk of being open-ended haha.) Really nice try. However, you are definitely on the right track with (ROT13) bar bs gur gvgyr uvagf.

Answer (score 5):

Please tell me you are:

> The car from "*A Night at the Roxbury*" with Doug and Steve Butabi along with barhop Jim Carrey inside:
>  [image: GIF from A Night at the Roxbury.]
>  Great puzzle!
>  <sub>***Note** This isn't a serious answer as it doesn't fit the title; however, it fit the one-liner so well that I just had to post it.*</sub>

Comment: Charming, haha. I'll post another hint, but this is nevertheless a great answer ;)